# How can I remove extra spaces in code passed through probsoln package?

Tags: verbatim, knitr, probsoln

This is an easy question to a potentially complicated situation. I'm using RStudio to write homework and exams using the `probsoln` package that embeds R code into the LaTeX directly. I am using `knitr` to do the actual weaving for me (yay for one button compile). I have had a *lot* of use out of this combination, and really enjoy using it. Huge kudo's to the `probsoln` author. But the one thing that still bothers me is the way code is parsed through the probsoln package.

**Extra spaces are added between characters or words in code.**

I have created a demo code that shows what the output looks like, what Id like it to look like, and what I would settle for. The PDF can be viewed [here](https://github.com/norcalbiostat/random/blob/master/test_probsoln.pdf).

**Is there something I can do to remove those spaces and have the code parse as normal verbatim, or better yet syntax highlighted code?**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{probsoln}

% Uncomment the following line to generate solution sheet.
\showanswers

% Load problems from external files, grouped type of problem
<<desc,child="samp_prblms.Rnw">>=
@

\begin{document}

Probsoln output. Adds extra spacing between certain characters. \\
\useproblem{test}


Desired output format.
<<warning=FALSE>>=
  library(MASS)
  f <- subset(survey, Sex=="female")
@

Verbatim output format. Acceptable, but missing syntax highlighting.
\begin{verbatim}
  library(MASS)
  f <- subset(survey, Sex=="female")
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

The samp_prblms.Rnw file defines the following question/solution pair.

```
\begin{defproblem}{test}[fragile]
Subset the survey data set in the MASS library to only include females.
\begin{onlysolution}[fragile]%
  \begin{solution}
  <<warning=FALSE>>=
  library(MASS)
  f <- subset(survey, Sex=="female")
  @
    \end{solution}
\end{onlysolution}
\end{defproblem}
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem as you. A partial solution I found is set `highlight = FALSE` option in knitr chunks or define it globally (see below). But this is sub optimal.

`<<include = FALSE>>=
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(highlight = FALSE)
@`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: Thanks! It's a step in the right direction. 
Now I wonder if @Yihui 's newest additions to `highr` can be modified to apply the syntax highlighting. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40252885/how-to-syntax-highlight-inline-r-code-in-r-markdown I feel like it's really a problem with the solution code being wrapped in verbatim.